# Add minutes from another column to string time column in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, date, pyspark, timestamp

I have the below pyspark dataframe.both are string columns.

```
time     additional_time_in_mins
11:00:00 60
13:00:00 60
14:00:00 30
```

I have to add the minutes in the additional time column to actual time and create an output as below in pyspark.

Expected output:

```
new_time
12:00:00
14:00:00
14:30:00
```

Is there a way to do this in pyspark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple option is converting `time` column to *bigint* in seconds using `unix_timestamp` function, add the minutes (*minutes * 60s*) and then cast the result back to *timestamp*.
Lastly, convert to hourly format.

```
df = df.withColumn('new_time', F.date_format((F.unix_timestamp('time', 'HH:mm:ss') + F.col('additional_time_in_mins')*60).cast('timestamp'), 'HH:mm:ss'))

df.show()

+--------+-----------------------+--------+
|    time|additional_time_in_mins|new_time|
+--------+-----------------------+--------+
|11:00:00|                     60|12:00:00|
|13:00:00|                     60|14:00:00|
|14:00:00|                     30|14:30:00|
+--------+-----------------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way to do this using UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format, col
data = [
  ("11:00:00", "60"),
  ("13:00:00", "60"),
  ("14:00:00", "30"),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["time", "additional_time_in_mins"])
df.show()
```

[image: Original datframe output]

UDF logic to sum time

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
@udf(returnType=StringType())
def sum_time(var_time, additional_time):
  # Converting var_time string to time
  var_time = datetime.strptime(var_time, '%H:%M:%S').time()
  #Using date to utitlise the time function
  combined_time = (datetime.combine(date.today(), var_time) + timedelta(minutes=additional_time)).time()
  return str(combined_time)
```

Using UDF to get the final output:

```
df = df.withColumn(
  "total_time", sum_time(col("time"), col("additional_time_in_mins").cast(IntegerType()))
)
display(df)
```

[image: Final output after applying udf]

Answer (score 0):

The following pyspark code worked for me:

```
df = df.withColumn('time_end',col('time_start')+expr('INTERVAL 5 minutes))
```